# why the second request will be blocked in chrome but not in firefox

Tags: python, django, google-chrome, firefox

I am using django to start a web server.

a test_sleep function like this,

```
# views.py
import time

from django.http import HttpResponse

def test_sleep(request):
    time.sleep(3)
    return HttpResponse('I am awake')
```

and this is my url:

```
...
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^test/', test_sleep),
]
...
```

when I visit the *test* url in two chrome tabs within 3 seconds(the time length for sleeping), the second request won't execute until the first finished. But when I use two firefox tabs, they can execute in the same time.

Using '*python manage.py runserver*' will turn the multi-threads on automatically, so why the second request will be blocked in the chrome browser?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently Chrome is behaving differently unlike Firefox. If you still tend to know the reason then contact the Chrome's support.

Otherwise your code is right and Django truly creates the multi-threads.

BTW:

It's convention in the URLS to write functions like `views.name_of_function`, because of class-based views which are written like `name_of_class.as_view()`.

Comment: Ok. Thanks Yaaaaaaaaaaay.